# Can I achieve a similar power usage to the i5-7500T with an i5-7500 by underclocking?

Tags: intel-core-i5, power-consumption, underclock

I'm upgrading my aging NAS hardware to something more recent, and I've decided that I will either buy an i5-7500 (3.4 base, 3.8 boost, 65W) or an i5-7500T  (2.7 base, 3.3 boost, 35W). Given that the two CPUs are so similar in price, I don't want to miss out on potential performance, but right now I am more keenly interested in lower energy consumption.

1) Will the CPUs use similar amounts of energy when at low utilization?

2) Can I underclock the i5-7500?

3) Would that achieve a similar power consumption to the i5-7500T?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Energy consumption is given for *maximum* dissipation, i.e. performing as many operations per second as possible. Since the CPU's have similar architecture, *under the same load*, i.e. the same number of operations/second, it is likely that the actual dissipation would be very similar for the two devices. Of course, the i5-7500 is *capable* of performing faster than the T variant.

Take into consideration that under most conditions, the NAS processor is loafing, so actual power conumption would be well below maximum dissipation. If you'd like to test the actual load on the NAS, try testing with the  [Intel NAS Performance Toolkit](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/storage/nas-performance-toolkit.html).

See [Passmark Sotware's benchmarks](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/Intel-Core-i5-7500-vs-Intel-Core-i5-7500T/2910vs2917) and calculated electrical costs for the two processors.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. I've never used Passmark's comparison page before; didn't know they had one!